# Fiori Elements List Report Object Page Row formatting

Tags: sapui5

with the annotation modeler I have added a header and a table to the Object Page.
The Table Data has some column data (e.g. Name, date of birth, sex [m/f]) only name and year are shown.

Dependent on the value of the column sex (m or f) I want to set the background color of the entire row to pink or blue. Additionally I want to reformat the date of birth that only the year is shown.

So far I've tried to add a formatter to the table, but haven't found a method to do it.

So what would be the best way to achieve this behavior.

Comment: What's the error you are getting in the formatter ??

Comment: I get no error, because I have not been able to set a formatter or found a way to do it inside onInit or so.